# Windows Installer: MsiDoAction() returns ERROR_FUNCTION_NOT_CALLED

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer, action

I am writing a bootstrapper for a product with several prerequisites. To determine which prereqs to install, I use MSI AppSearch.

The bootstrapper opens the **myproduct.msi** package with `::MsiOpenPackageEx()`, then calls `::MsiDoAction("AppSearch")` to load the properties, and finally fetches the properties of interest to determine which prereqs need loading. I then close the prereqs session (`::MsiCloseHandle()`) so it won't interfere with any MSI sessions used by the prereqs installers. Ultimately (after prereqs are installed) the bootstrapper runs `msiexec /i myproduct.msi`.

I want to extend this by calling a custom action `::MsiDoAction("MyExtendedAppSearch")` which will populate additional MSI properties during the prereqs session, using WMI to do searches that MSI AppSearch cannot do. However, when I call that action, it returns `ERROR_FUNCTION_NOT_CALLED`. The same action, when called in a *real* install session, works just fine.

I have tried this with both a C .dll and with VBScript (embedded, `Binary` table, doesn't matter). Apparently there is some sort of initialization done in a real install that I am not doing. Also or alternatively, I'm not setting the right flag bits on the action, or should be scheduling it in `InstallExecuteSequence` (or not, or something).

Your guidance will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: After which standard action is your custom action scheduled and in which sequence table? MsiDoAction can only call UI actions and execute actions scheduled before InstallInitialize. Did you try scheduling your custom action right after AppSearch?

Answer (score 1):

@Cosmin Pirvu: it's not scheduled at all, nor in any sequence table. It exists only in the CustomAction table, and is called explicitly by the chainer program.

Never mind, folks. False alarm/sloppy programmer.

Meta-solution: read your predecessor's code carefully, and read the docs even more carefully.

Solution: `::MsiOpenPackageEx()` was being called with the `MSIOPENPACKAGEFLAGS_IGNOREMACHINESTATE` flag. Per the MSI documentation, using that flag returns a *restricted* session handle that cannot call .dll, .exe or script custom actions.

*Not* passing that flag -- or, equivalently, calling `::MsiOpenPackage()` (no `Ex`) -- returns an unrestricted handle that *can*  .dll, .exe or script custom actions.